# Javascript Validation (gen_validatorv4.js ) - based on checkbox results

Tags: javascript, php, validation, dom-events

I created an order form as follows which contains multiple checkboxes to add items, Now I want to do the validation for disabled items when only user click on the related check box, Kindly help me to correct the following code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function check_box2(status)
{
status=!status;
document.orderform.item2.disabled = status;
document.orderform.qty2.disabled = status;
}
function check_box3(status)
{
status=!status; 
document.orderform.item3.disabled = status;
document.orderform.qty3.disabled = status;
}
function check_box4(status)
{
status=!status; 
document.orderform.item4.disabled = status;
document.orderform.qty4.disabled = status;
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<body onload="check_box2(status); check_box3(status); check_box4(status);">
<form action="order.php" method="POST" name="orderform" id="orderform" onSubmit="return validation();">
<table>
<tr><td valign="top"> <p>Order Item 1 :</p> </td><td> <select id="item1" name="item1">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"><p> [Select] </p></option>
      <option value="1"> <p> Product 1 </p></option>
      <option value="2"> <p> Product 2 </p> </option>
      <option value="3"> <p> Product 3 </p> </option>
</select> </td>

<td valign="top"><p>Quantity :</p></td><td><input style="width:30px;" name="qty1" type="text"></td> </tr>

<tr><td valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="check2" onclick="check_box2(this.checked)" >Add Item 2 : </td><td> <select id="item2" name="item2">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"><p> [Select] </p></option>
      <option value="1"> <p> Product 1 </p></option>
      <option value="2"> <p> Product 2 </p> </option>
      <option value="3"> <p> Product 3 </p> </option>
</select> </td>

<td valign="top"><p>Quantity :</p></td><td><input style="width:30px;" name="qty2" type="text"></td> </tr>

<tr><td valign="middle"> <input type="checkbox" name="check3" onclick="check_box3(this.checked)" >Add Item 3 :  </td><td> <select id="item3">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"><p> [Select] </p></option>
      <option value="1"> <p> Product 1 </p></option>
      <option value="2"> <p> Product 2 </p> </option>
      <option value="3"> <p> Product 3 </p> </option>
</select> </td>

<td valign="top"><p>Quantity :</p></td><td><input style="width:30px;" name="qty3" type="text"></td> </tr>

<tr><td valign="middle"> <input type="checkbox" name="check4" onclick="check_box4(this.checked)" >Add Item 4 :  </td><td> <select id="item4">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"><p> [Select] </p></option>
      <option value="1"> <p> Product 1 </p></option>
      <option value="2"> <p> Product 2 </p> </option>
</select> </td>

<td valign="top"><p>Quantity :</p></td><td><input style="width:30px;" name="qty4" type="text"></td> </tr>

</table>

<div><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"> </div>
</form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("orderform");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("item1","dontselect=0", "Please select an item");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("qty1","req","Please enter your quantity");

    if  (document.orderform.item2.checked==true)
    {
       frmvalidator.addValidation("item2","dontselect=0", "Please select an item2");
       frmvalidator.addValidation("qty2","req","Please enter your quantity");
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add some conditions:

```
if(document.getElementById('checkbox123').checked == true) {
  // validate code here
}
```

You can do it like this as well:

```
if(document.orderform.checkbox123.checked == true) {
  // validate code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I tried , if(document.orderform.checkbox123.checked == true){} as you can see it on my code, but it is not working for me

Comment: Are you using Firebug or something similar to see console errors? If not look into this it helps when developing JavaScript. You can even do entire codes in them and execute to test before adding the codes to your site. I developed a huge indoor map overlay and would not have been able to do so without the console.

Comment: No I'm not using a Firebug, will check it on , Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Able to do the validation by using VWZ_IsChecked() function which is included in gen_validatorv4.js script

```
frmvalidator.addValidation("item2","dontselect=0", "Please select an item2",
    "VWZ_IsChecked(document.forms['orderform'].elements['check2'],'check2')");


frmvalidator.addValidation("qty2","req","Please enter your quantity for item 2",
    "VWZ_IsChecked(document.forms['orderform'].elements['check2'],'check2')");
```